Delay in action controlled by timer?
I created a python script that changes the color of an object for a set period of time, then switches it back once another amount of time has passed. When reviewing the script on its own, it's been working as intended. However, I noticed that when I placed that section of code into a script with more code that was in a file with more models, the delay between the color switch was longer than I intended it to be. It's a looping script, which I think might be the cause. Besides that, are there any other possible issues that could be causing this? I pasted the relevant section of the code here.
        def run():
            global counter
            if mytool.meter == 'OP1':
                counter += 0.01
                counter = round(counter, 2)
                if counter <= 0.25:
                    bpy.data.materials["Glow"].node_tree.nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value = 0
                    bpy.data.node_groups["NodeGroup"].nodes["Mix"].inputs[7].default_value = (1, 0, 0, 1)
                else:
                    bpy.data.materials["Glow"].node_tree.nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value = 1
                    bpy.data.node_groups["NodeGroup"].nodes["Mix"].inputs[7].default_value = (0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1)
                if counter == 0.35:
                    counter = 0
                print (counter)
                return 0.01
        bpy.app.timers.register(run)     

I'm still very much an amateur with this, so any help on how to fix it would be appreciated.

To switch between two states, two functions with the same period can be registered with a phase lag. It is less time consuming than checking inside a single one which state is the active one. Following is a demonstration where the default material color is changing between red and blue every 0.5s. The set_red function is registered to start at t=0s, and it is called every 1s. The set_blue function is registered to start at t=0.5s, and it is called every 1s also. Consequently, from 0s to 0.5s the color is red ; then from 0.5s to 1s it is blue ; then from 1s to 1.5s it is red again ; and so on...
import bpy

def set_red():
     bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Base Color'].default_value = (1,0,0,0)
     return 1
    
def set_blue():
     bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Base Color'].default_value = (0,0,1,0)
     return 1
     
bpy.app.timers.register(set_red, first_interval=0)
bpy.app.timers.register(set_blue, first_interval=0.5)

Resources: see Application Timers.
